# C: What is the output of the following code? And please explain

Tags: c, logical-operators, post-increment, pre-increment

```
int a = 5;
if(a==a++){
   printf("true 1");
}
if(a==++a){
   printf("true 2");
}
```

When I run this code, it prints "true 2". I do not understand how. Please help.
Also, how is logical equivalence computed in precedence with increment operators?

Comment: It will output a PIZZA with extra cheese.

Comment: This code yields random results because your variable "a" is initialized to random value each time you run it.

Comment: I got double pepperoni with mine.

Comment: UB in as many ways as possible.

Comment: Come on, this question is asked once every couple of days. Please read an introductory text on the `++` operators and search the archive before asking this question again.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how increment works with ==. I couldn't find it anywhere. I'm sorry if it's being repeated.

Comment: I don't understand why these questions come up in university/interview questions. The right answer is: "Stop writing programs like this! What are you doing!"

Comment: @AshaAravind not just repeated . but disgorged onto SO multple times by every generation of student.  Please ask your prof/TA to not issue such homework in future.

Comment: I mean, just your title alone :'C: What is the output of the following code?' - you already know the answer: ' When I run this code, it prints "true 2" ',so why ask?

Comment: @RichardTingle It's actually an excellent interview question. If the candidate starts to ponder what the result will be, instead of simply dismissing the code as nonsense, they failed.

Comment: As for this specific case, it would be interesting to hear what they expected the code to do. `if (a == a)` or `if (a == a+1)` are the two alternatives. I would love to hear how either would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation in `a==++a` is not defined by the standard. Thus the `++` can be performed before the comparison or after comparison. With another compiler you can get different results. This is called 'UB', or 'Undefined Behavior'.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give Undefined Behavior in many ways. But if you initialize `a`, the difference is that `++a` will return the incremented value, while `a++` will return the new value.

Also, in `for` loops, you should use `++a` and you will not go wrong.

Let's evaluate your problem.

In the first case, when you compare `a` with the incremented value of `a` (as `a++` return the incremented value), so it is false. Example: `a` has 5, and the incremented value is 6. So, as they do not match, it will be a false.

In the second case, when you compare `a` with the old value of `a` (as `++a` returns the original value), you get true. Example: `a` has 5 and when you increment it using `++a`, you get the old/original value, which is also 5. Thus, you get a true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
So, when a is post-incremented or pre-incremented won't the if condition always return true? Since we are equating it with a itself?

Comment: @AshaAravind, no, i'll explain that. Wait for a few minutes. I'll add it in my answer.